# Snort install issue on debian 6 with libpcre - libpcre library not found

Tags: linux, snort

I've read the manual on snort.org for installing snort on Debian but am still having an issue. Does anyone know how to resolve this? I've tried installing the libpcre3 amd libpcre3-dev packages by using apt-get and also manually installing by downloading the latest version off the tcpdump website. Any ideas?

Checking for pcre-compile in -l pcre...no
Error! Libpcre library not found.
Get it from http://www.pcre.org

Comment: Can you compile a simple executable against `pcre` like this? `int main(int argc, char* argv) { return 0; }` -- `gcc -o hello hello.c -lpcre`

Comment: It compiled fine.

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Comment: not sure which you may need but try installing some of these others:

Answer (score 0):

Install package libpcre with `sudo apt install  libpcre++-dev`

Answer (score -1):

not sure which you may need but try installing some of these others:

aptitude search libpcre

p   libpcre++-dev                   - C++ wrapper class for pcre (development)

p   libpcre++0                      - C++ wrapper class for pcre (runtime)

p   libpcre-ocaml                   - OCaml bindings for PCRE (runtime)

p   libpcre-ocaml-dev               - OCaml bindings for PCRE (Perl Compatible R

v   libpcre-ocaml-dev-g7y84         -

v   libpcre-ocaml-g7y84             -

i   libpcre3                        - Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Libra

p   libpcre3-dbg                    - Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Libra

p   libpcre3-dev                    - Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Libra

p   libpcrecpp0                     - Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Libra